# Ajax call to PHP function - saving picture gallery from settings page in Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Can someone show me a good example of how to call a PHP function with Ajax? I'm trying to save an image gallery (with dynamic number of images) to database in the admin settings section. The below code is incomplete or maybe with some errors. Please show me a good example or a better way:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="jsAddSettingsFields()">Save Changes</button>
```

```js
function jsAddSettingsFields(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var urlsdata = new Array();

    for (var i = 0, element; element = elements[i++];) {
        if (elements[i].id == "idGalPic") {
            urlsdata[i] = elements[i].src; 
            // now we have all image urls in array, now need to 
            // call add_settings_fields

            var data = {
                action: 'php_addsettingsfields',
                p_urls: urlsdata //I think i need to JSON this
            };
            jQuery.post( "", function( data ) );
        }
    }
}//end of js function
```

```php
<?php
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_options', 'php_addsettingsfields_callback' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_update_options', 'php_addsettingsfields_callback' );

    function php_addsettingsfields_callback() {
        $pic_urls = $_POST['p_urls'];  // De-JSON-fy this variable

        foreach ($pic_urls as &$url) {
            add_settings_field($url);
        }
        add_settings_field(
            'pic_url_id', // ID - slug name of field
            '', // Title 
            array( $this, 'pic_gal_callback' ), // Callback
            'TestPlugin', // Page
            'setting_section_id' // Section ID - slug name of page         
        );   

        public function pic_gal_callback()  {
            <input type="hidden" id="idPic" name="idPic" value=$url />
        }

        // after all hidden fields(with gallery pic urls) are added to setting section submit 
        // the page and save the gallery urls to database
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here take a look at a working ajax example from one of my plugins.

Javascript Part:

```
//setting click event on button click to fire a function
$('#YourButtonIdHere').click(function () {
    YourFunctionNameHere();
});

//function to execute
function YourFunctionNameHere() {
    //formdata variable consists of
    //action: this is ajax action name for WordPress which we define in PHP with a callback function with same name. See in PHP code part.
    //$('#YourFormIDHere').serialize();    //this gets content from form and serialize it. 
    var frm_data = "action=your_action_name_here&" + $('#YourFormIDHere').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl, // since WordPress version 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
        data: frm_data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //do stuff here in case of success
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //do stuff here in case of error
        }
    });
}
```

PHP Part:

```
 //here wp_ajax is the required prefix for your custom actions
 //first parameter is action name with wp_ajax prefix
 //second parameter is callback function to execute with same name as your action
 //for example if your action name is wp_ajax_save_settings then your callback will be save_settings
add_action( 'wp_ajax_your_action_name_here', 'your_action_name_here' );

function your_action_name_here() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    //do stuff here and echo response
    echo "ajax call success";
    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response

}
```

Comment: Damn this Javascript is driving me crazy. Can you please help me correct this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/direktor/2rqgfh3z/2/

I want to get all image elements URLs and put them into array and stringify them to Json. Why it's not working?

Comment: Here I forked your fiddle and solved the issue you were having. Here's the new link https://jsfiddle.net/elucinator/fLntdpux/15/